# Exclude Parts of JavaScript Regex Match

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need a regex to match `"Google search"` from  `<a title="Google search" href="http://google.com">Google</a>`.

[Here](http://regexr.com/393a1) is the link to regexr.com.

I need it to only match for `<a>` tags.  I don't excel at regex, but I do know with JavaScript, look-behinds are impossible.  I need it to somehow look-behind, and check if `title=".+"` comes **after** `<a>`.

Here are a few regular expressions that I put together:

This expression kinda works, but it picks up `title=""` in `<img>`.  Also, it picks up `title=` in `<a>`, when I only want `"Google search"` and `"Microsoft home"`.

```
/((title=".+")(?=\s*href))|(title=".+")/igm;
```

[image]

These expressions removes the `title=` like I want, but it also adds a `\s` at the end.

```
/(?!title=)".+"\s+/igm; AND /(?!title)".+"\s+\b/igm;
```

[image]

In conclusion, given the above HTML, I want it to ONLY match `"Google search"` and `"Microsoft home"` (I don't want it to include the `title=` nor match `title="..."` in `<img/>`)

---

**EDIT:**

This regular expression I was working on ONLY matches the first `<a>` title:

```
/(?!<a\s+title\=)("[^"]+")(?=\s*href)/igm;
```

[image]

Comment: [A must read](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript). But why don't you simply use the DOM?

Comment: so you want to select the whole link ? would you please post your html as well ? and i prefer https://www.debuggex.com/ for testing. may you try your testings here.

Answer (score 0):

This regex:

```
/<a[^>]+title=(["'])(Google search|Microsoft home)\1/ig
```

Captures ONLY Google search or Microsoft home in **a** tags.  The match includes the tags.  Don't fret!  We captured the "Google Search" in the second capture group.  You can access it in javascript with \2 or $2.

Comment: I forgot to mention, Google search, and Microsoft home can be anything.  Those are random

Comment: That can be fixed.  But have you tested this one?  Is it working (besides what you just mentioned)?